# NullReferenceException while Reading XML File with Linq (C# 4.0)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, nullreferenceexception

I'm completely stumped, I've used very similar code before and it worked perfectly, the XML in this was written by a separate method in this program and I checked it against it and it looked fine

That's the code for parsing the XML file

```
UserType CurrentUser = new UserType();
XDocument UserDoc = XDocument.Load(Path2UserFile);

XElement UserRoot = UserDoc.Element("User");
CurrentUser.User_ID = int.Parse(UserDoc.Element("User_ID").Value);
CurrentUser.Full_Name = UserDoc.Element("Full_Name").Value;
CurrentUser.Gender = UserDoc.Element("Gender").Value;
CurrentUser.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(UserDoc.Element("Birthdate").Value);
CurrentUser.PersonType = int.Parse(UserDoc.Element("PersonType").Value);
CurrentUser.Username = UserDoc.Element("Username").Value;
CurrentUser.Password = UserDoc.Element("Password").Value;
CurrentUser.Email_Address = UserDoc.Element("Email_Address").Value;
```

The `Path2UserFile` points to the correct file as well, and I had it write out the full path.

It has a **NullReferenceException whenever it tries to parse the contents of any of the elements**

The XML File follows this format

```
<User>
  <User_ID>11</User_ID>
  <Full_Name>Sample User</Full_Name>
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
  <BirthDate>12/12/2010 12:00:00 AM</BirthDate>
  <PersonType>2</PersonType>
  <Username>Sample User</Username>
  <Password>sample123</Password>
  <Email_adddress>sampleuser@gmail.com</Email_adddress>
</User>
```

The `UserType` class looks like this

```
class UserType
{
        public int User_ID = 0;
        public string Full_Name = string.Empty;
        public string Gender = string.Empty;
        public DateTime BirthDate;
        public int PersonType = 0;
        public string Username = string.Empty;
        public string Password = string.Empty;
        public string Email_Address = string.Empty;
}
```

I have no clue as to what's wrong, any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all the `UserDoc` references to `UserRoot` (the ones after the `UserRoot` declaration). Since the object is an `XDocument` rather than an `XElement` you need to operate at that level. Otherwise you can refer to `UserDoc.Root.Element(...)` instead but that's lengthier.

```
UserType CurrentUser = new UserType();
XDocument UserDoc = XDocument.Load(Path2UserFile);

XElement UserRoot = UserDoc.Root;
CurrentUser.User_ID = int.Parse(UserRoot.Element("User_ID").Value);
CurrentUser.Full_Name = UserRoot.Element("Full_Name").Value;
CurrentUser.Gender = UserRoot.Element("Gender").Value;
CurrentUser.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(UserRoot.Element("BirthDate").Value);
CurrentUser.PersonType = int.Parse(UserRoot.Element("PersonType").Value);
CurrentUser.Username = UserRoot.Element("Username").Value;
CurrentUser.Password = UserRoot.Element("Password").Value;
CurrentUser.Email_Address = UserRoot.Element("Email_address").Value;
```

Also, be aware of your case. Use `BirthDate` instead of `Birthdate` (capital "D" to match your XML). Similarly, it's `Email_address` not `Email_Address` (lowercase "a") and your XML has 3 D's in "address" (spelling mistake).

Comment: @Indebi no problem. Please re-read my answer too. I pointed out a few other issues since your comment was made.